# Accessing SymbolInfo from modified SyntaxNode in Roslyn SyntaxRewriter

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm creating a SyntaxRewriter which marked classes as partial and methods as virtual if the class inherits from a certain type

To do this I'm looking up the SymbolInfo from the Semantic Model inside the Rewriter, the issue that I'm having is that once I modify the syntaxtree to make a class partial, I have invalidated the SemanticModel and cannot use it to get the SymbolInfo for methods.

A rough example of the rewriter is below, the .InheritsFrom< T >() is an extension method that just walks the inheritance to find usages of a particular type, I just stuck IDisposable in as an example but it's not really important what the type is.
The .WithPartialModifier() is again just an extension method to add the partial to the class syntaxnode modifiers.

It may be that I need to switch my approach or update the compilation with the new syntaxtree but I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
public class RewriterPartial : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    private readonly CSharpCompilation _compiler;

    public RewriterPartial(CSharpCompilation compiler)
    {
        this._compiler = compiler;
    }

    public override SyntaxNode VisitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        var symbol = _compiler.GetSemanticModel(node.SyntaxTree).GetDeclaredSymbol(node);
        if (symbol.InheritsFrom<System.IDisposable>())
        {
            if (!node.Modifiers.Any(SyntaxKind.PartialKeyword))
            {
                node = node.WithPartialModifier();
            }
        }

        return base.VisitClassDeclaration(node);
    }

    public override SyntaxNode VisitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        var model = _compiler.GetSemanticModel(node.SyntaxTree);
        // fails above here as the node modified above 
        // and its SyntaxTree have no CompilationUnit
        // and I need to repeat the .InheritsFrom<T> call
        // to check if the method comes from a class in the syntaxtree
        // that inherits from the specific type
        return node;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can visit and modify the deepest nodes first by calling `base.VisitClassDeclaration(node);` before modifying the tree.

Try the following:

```
public class RewriterPartial : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    private readonly CSharpCompilation _compilation;
    public RewriterPartial(CSharpCompilation compilation, SemanticModel model)
    {
        this._compilation = compilation;
    }

    public override SyntaxNode VisitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        //Visit the deepest nodes before modifying the tree.
        var newNode = (ClassDeclarationSyntax)base.VisitClassDeclaration(node);
        if (!newNode.Modifiers.Any(SyntaxKind.PartialKeyword))
        {
            newNode = newNode.WithModifiers(
                SyntaxFactory.TokenList(
                    SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PartialKeyword)));
        }
        return newNode;
    }

    public override SyntaxNode VisitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        var model = _compilation.GetSemanticModel(node.SyntaxTree);
        var symbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(node);
        //Do whatever you need to here
        return node;
    }
}
```